# (Easy) Isoline N(t)

Tags: linear-algebra, finance

I'm sitting with an assignment statistics and functions, and one question in particular has got me perplexed:

An isoline N(t) is given by 
$$f(x,y)=t.$$
*What is N(t)?*

I know from previous questions that $$f(x,y)=3000x+2000y$$

Now, how do I find $N(t)$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It is a contour line...along that line $f(x,y)=constant$. If you change $t$ you get different contour lines, so $3000x+2000y=t$ represents all the contour lines varying $t$.

Comment: Thank you! So is $N(t)$ is $3000x+2000y$?

Comment: $N(t)$ is the set of contour lines: $3000x+2000y=t$; if you fix $t$, you get one particular contour line.

Comment: I think I get it now. So $N(t)$ doesn't have a value - it's just the set of the lines. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

$N(t)$ is $f(x,y)$. the distribution $n(t)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.
therefore $N(t)=f(x,y)=t$.